# Detect clearing browser cookies in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have searched this for long time, unfortunately I couldn't find a helpful answer. when a user accessing my asp.net mvc 5 application and do a clear cookies from his browser, how can I detect that the cookies has been flushed and sign out the user without refreshing the page?

I have noticed this feature in Gmail. it automatically detects cookies flushing and redirect you to the login page.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Almost every login pipeline use **cookie**.

Usually you store some sort of `userHash` or even `loginToken` in **cookies** on login action.

So you don't detect that **cookies** flushed. You just check **cookie** exists on every request and if not - you redirect user.

Comment: If you noticed that when you logged in inside your gmail account, and do a clear history action, the page automatically gets refreshed and log you out! I have came up with an idea of a javascript function that checks on the authentication cookies every 1 sec, and if the cookie has been flushed, redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: Wrong, function is not check cookies existance, gmail just check emal or messages. The workflow that i described it answer